# can i do lazy loading in Nhibernate at runtime using c#

Tags: nhibernate

I am new in implement Nhibernete.

If i use XML documents (.hbm.xml files) in Nhibernete, i enable/disable lazy loading in that xml.

Is there any way in Nhibernete where i can set lazy loading at run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you not to define lazy loading/eager loading in your hbm file.

You can control everything using [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)

Lazy loading:

```
var order = Session.QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
    .Where(x => x.id == 12)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Eager loading:

```
Domain.OrderLine orderLine = null;

var order = Session.QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
    .Where(x => x.id == 12)
    .Fetch(x => x.OrderLines).Eager
        .JoinAlias(x => x.OrderLines, () => orderLine, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

or

```
var order = Session.QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
    .Where(x => x.id == 12)
        .Inner.JoinAlias(x => x.OrderLines, () => orderLine)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

I would suggest you to read this interesting [article](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it).