# NHibernate QueryOver can't query lazily loaded objects

Tags: linq, nhibernate, queryover

I have the following NHibernate code:

```
return NHibernateHelper.Session.QueryOver<SubProject>()
.Where
(
    sp => sp.CompletedDate == null
        && sp.ImportanceFlag.FlagID != GlobalConstants.ImportanceFlagID_Blue
        && sp.Project.SalesStatus.StatusID != GlobalConstants.SalesStatusID_NotSet
        && sp.Project.ProjectID != Guid.Empty
)
.OrderBy(sp => sp.Project.Client.CompanyName).Asc
.ThenBy(sp => sp.Project.ProjectName).Asc
.ThenBy(sp => sp.SubProjectName).Asc
.List();
```

However when it gets executed, returns the following exception message:

> could not resolve property: Project.CompletedDate of:
>   TaskManager.Framework.Model.SubProject

Do I have to use JoinQueryOver similar to this: [Nhibernate Linq query to QueryOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997146/nhibernate-linq-query-to-queryover)

And if so, how do I join multiple objects from SubProject?

Thanks :)
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get that error message cause **Subproject** entity doesn't load **Project** related entity.

Your statement should look something like this:

```
Project project = null;

return NHibernateHelper.Session.QueryOver<SubProject>()
.Where
(
    sp => sp.CompletedDate == null
        && sp.ImportanceFlag.FlagID != GlobalConstants.ImportanceFlagID_Blue
)
.Inner.JoinAlias(sp => sp.Project, () => project)
.And(()=> project.SalesStatus.StatusID != GlobalConstants.SalesStatusID_NotSet
        && project.ProjectID != Guid.Empty
    )
.OrderBy(() => project.Client.CompanyName).Asc
.ThenBy(() => project.ProjectName).Asc
.ThenBy(sp => sp.SubProjectName).Asc
.List();
```

I am not sure about the relation between Project and Client but I guess a Project has always an associated Client and so it should a many-to-one with a fetch-join.

If you want to know more about joins and fetching I've [replied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036538/219406) to another user few weeks ago.

And here's an interesting [article](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/04/nhibernate-querying-relationships-are-depth/) about the same topic.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I eventually found that joins was what I was after :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ for that query instead of QueryOver (in fact, the tags you chose suggest this is what you actually wanted):

```
return NHibernateHelper.Session.Query<SubProject>()
.Where
(
    sp => sp.CompletedDate == null
        && sp.ImportanceFlag.FlagID != GlobalConstants.ImportanceFlagID_Blue
        && sp.Project.SalesStatus.StatusID != GlobalConstants.SalesStatusID_NotSet
        && sp.Project.ProjectID != Guid.Empty
)
.OrderBy(sp => sp.Project.Client.CompanyName)
.ThenBy(sp => sp.Project.ProjectName)
.ThenBy(sp => sp.SubProjectName)
.ToList();
```

Comment: +1 - you're answer also works, shame I can't mark two as correct!